# Should the datetimepicker tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion

The [datetimepicker tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/datetimepicker/info) has two problems in my opinion. Firstly, the name of the tag is incorrect because *datetimepicker* is not a word. However, I can understand why this name was introduced, since some UI libraries have used [some](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231249(v=vs.60).aspx) [version](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) [of](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index) this as a proper noun. Given that the tag excerpt also uses *Datetimepicker* I'm assuming that this isn't simply a question of tag formatting. I propose that the name used should be date-time picker and following [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) the tag should be renamed 'date-time-picker'.

Secondly, the tag is potentially too broad as it *seems* to cover date-time pickers, date pickers and time pickers. Date pickers and time pickers are separate controls which are not always used in tandem, while, a date-time picker is a combination of the two. Should this tag cover all these controls or should it be divided into multiple tags?